# Polymorphic C++ with Pure Virtual Function destructor

Tags: c++, qt

I am not sure if the following code is safe from memory leak.

```
#ifndef RENDERABLE_H
#define RENDERABLE_H

class QGLShaderProgram;
class GLWidget;
class BoundingBox;

class Renderable{

public:
    virtual void update(float duration) = 0;
    virtual void render(QGLShaderProgram& shader, float duration) = 0;
    virtual BoundingBox* getBBox() const = 0;
    virtual void translate(float xx, float yy, float zz) = 0;
    virtual void rotate(float degrees_x, float degrees_y, float degrees_z) = 0;
    virtual void scale(float xx, float yy, float zz) = 0;
};

#endif // RENDERABLE_H
```

The above "interface" is been implemented by object3d.cpp. We may then add many Object3D objects into a Scene object if they belong to the same scene. However, upon the end of the scene, I want to ensure there is no memory leak and so I would call delete on everything. However, in the scene object, I have the following variable:

```
QVector<Renderable*>* sceneObjects;
QVector<GLTexture2D*>* sceneTextures;
QMap<QString, Material*>* sceneMaterials;
```

As you can see,

```
delete sceneObjects;
delete sceneTextures;
delete sceneMaterials;
```

should delete the QVector and according to Qt, it should call the destructor of those objects in it. However, Qt documentation were not clear about object POINTERS. Would Qt delete object pointers with their proper destructor? Additionally, what happens to Renderable pointers? As you can see from the "interface" that it has no destructor.

Thanks for any input.
ChaoSXDemon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your `Renderable` class must have a virtual destructor, because calling `delete` on a base pointer to a derived object is undefined behaviour without one.

Second, no, you will need to loop through and call `delete` on each pointer (or, [as Nikos noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13077915/726361), use [`qDeleteAll`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-2) as long as *every* object in the container is allocated with plain `new` (and not `new[]` or `malloc` or anything else)) in each container to make sure their memory is reclaimed (how could Qt know if the pointers point to things allocated by `new`? They could point to things allocated by `new[]`, things on the heap, the stack, or somewhere else).

If you don't want to do that, you can store `unique_ptr`s in the containers and then the destructors of the `unique_ptr`s will be called when you `delete` the containers, and those destructors will deallocate the memory they own. No need to manually deallocate them or use `qDeleteAll`.

Comment: So I guess the destructor has to be pure virtual too?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon not pure virtual, just virtual. You can make it pure virtual, but there wouldn't be any point to that, and it _must_ have a definition anyway.

Comment: What should I write in my implementation object such that for w/e object that is using Renderable it will call the correct desturctor?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon it will automatically call the correct destructors, you don't need to call them manually. But you do have to explicitly write a virtual one in `Renderable`, even if it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete each pointer manually. You don't need to iterate over every one manually though. You can do this very easily with:

```
qDeleteAll(*sceneObjects);
delete sceneObjects;
```

Same for your other containers. `qDeleteAll` is documented here: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtalgorithms.html#qDeleteAll-2

Also add a virtual dtor, as Seth Carnegie mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, it's working correctly now. However, it seems that QVector<Renderable*> rItems can't locate my items. Suppose I have: Renderable* o1 = new Object3D() and later I call (after rItems.append(o1)), rItems.remove(rItems.indexOf(o1)) it gives me index array out of bound. Specifically the index returned is -1. Any ideas why?

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon `indexOf()` returns -1 when it can't find the element. It's the only way it can tell you "not found." (Remember that Qt doesn't use exception handling.) You shouldn't just use its return value as an index; check for `< 0` first.